# Increase paste speed of two columns in data.table in R (reproducible)

Tags: r, performance, time, data.table

**I have data like this:**

```
library(data.table)
NN = 10000000
set.seed(32040)
DT <- data.table(
  col = 1:10000000,
  timestamp = 1521872652 + sample(7000001, NN, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I'm trying to pull the unique year and week as a code so I can sort duplicates (the real data table has userID along with much more). I **have a current solution that works (below), but it's slow** on the part pasting weeks and year uniquely from the date column. The creation of the date using `anytime` package and pulling `week` and `year` from `lubridate` are still very fast. Can someone help me speed this up? Thanks!

**My slow code (works but I'd like to speed it up)**:

```
library(anytime)
library(lubridate)
tz<-"Africa/Addis_Ababa"
DT$localtime<-  anytime(DT$timestamp, tz=tz) ###Lightning fast
DT$weekuni <- paste(year(DT$localtime),week(DT$localtime),sep="") ###super slow
```

My tests show it's the `paste` that's killing me:

Very fast `anytime` conversion to date:

```
system.time(DT$localtime<-  anytime(DT$timestamp, tz=tz)) ###Lightning fast
       user  system elapsed 
      0.264   0.417   0.933
```

Fast `lubridate` week and year conversion from date, but slow `paste`:

```
> system.time(DT$weekuni1 <- week(DT$localtime)) ###super slow
   user  system elapsed 
  1.203   0.188   1.400 
> system.time(DT$weekuni2 <- year(DT$localtime))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.229   0.189   1.427 
> system.time(DT$weekuni <- paste0(DT$weekuni1,dt$weekuni2))
   user  system elapsed 
 14.652   0.344  15.483
```

Comment: There's already a `year` and `week` function in pkg:data.table. Seems unwise to overwrite those if efficiency is a concern. And the function is spelled `paste` but this use is not consistent with the `[paste]` tag definiton. I would have thought that using the `:=` function from data.table would be the way to go rather than using `$.data.frame`

Comment: Your suggestion is a bit faster, but still slower than I think should be possible given a time column coming from anytime: ```> system.time(dt <- dt[,weekuni:=paste0(year(dt$localtime),week(dt$localtime)),])
   user  system elapsed 
  6.285   0.412   6.739 ```

Comment: Well, you are making two extra vectors and then coercing them to character before appending them. I'm not sure why that should be lightning fast.

Comment: Fair, I'm just seeing if there is a faster solution than what I have. Appreciate the suggestion, I'm new(ish) to data.table so the lubridate and data.frame solutions still come more naturally to me, thus your suggestion does help since I didn't know data table had native week() and year(), I'm just thinking if anytime can convert that whole column in .25 seconds, why does paste and the date functions take so long? Seems like there would be a super fast substr solution, and that isn't what I have found so far.

Comment: You should pay attention to the masking messages that appear when packages are loaded.

Comment: Also: don't use `<-` to create a new variable in a `data.table`, but use `:=` instead.
For example:
  `dt[, weekuni := paste0(year(localtime), week(localtime))]`

Comment: lubridates year/week functions may well be faster. we rely on POSIXlt conversion, which can be slow.

Comment: _"so I can sort duplicates"_ is a bit vague, but it doesn't seem to require `paste`. Can you please show us your _ultimate_ goal with this exercise, using a minimal data set (10-ish rows). Cheers.

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Yes, Found out by experiment that dt[ , weekuni  := paste0(as.POSIXlt(localtime)$year, as.POSIXlt(localtime)$week) ] was very much slower than either the original code or `dt[ , weekuni  := paste0(year(dt$localtime), week(dt$localtime))]` without lubridate loaded. Using data.table date functions inproved by about 30%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made your code run about 50% faster using `format` instead of `paste`.

First, I'm not sure the point of `anytime` for your use case since we can just throw the timestamp into a `POSIXct` structure almost instantly:

```
DT[ , localtime := .POSIXct(timestamp, tz = tz)]
```

Next, I searched around on `?strptime` for the ISO-week-based formatting codes to get:

```
DT[ , weekuni := format(localtime, format = '%G%V')]
```

I'm not 100% sure this will always be the same as `paste(year, week)`, but it was for your test data; if there *is* a difference between them, you should ask if that really matters for you.

The only thing I can think of that might be faster would be to use integer arithmetic on the timestamp itself. This is substantially easier if `Africa/Addis_Ababa` time zone doesn't have any adjustment to its UTC offset in your sample timeframe (unfortunately, it looks like `Africa/Addis_Ababa` observes daylight savings time, so the UTC offset varies between 2 & 3 hours, making the integer arithmetic approach substantially more difficult)

---

For the record, using `data.table::year` and `data.table::week` is about as fast as the approach used here, *but* it uses a different definition of "year" and "week" than `lubridate` (which by default uses the ISO year/week that `%G%V` does above).

`data.table` doesn't yet have an `isoyear` implementation, and `data.table::isoweek` is substantially slower than `lubridate::week`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to define a year-week based only on the date, you can get a solution that's 20 times faster:

```r
library(data.table)
NN = 10000000
# NN = 1e4
set.seed(32040)
DT <- data.table(
  col = seq_len(NN),
  timestamp = 1521872652 + sample(7000001, NN, replace = TRUE)
)
DT1 <- copy(DT)

DT2 <- copy(DT)
tz <- "Africa/Addis_Ababa"

old <- function(DT) {
  DT$localtime<-  anytime::anytime(DT$timestamp, tz=tz) ###Lightning fast
  DT$weekuni <- paste(lubridate::year(DT$localtime), lubridate::week(DT$localtime), sep="")
  DT[, timestamp := NULL]
  DT[, .(col, localtime, weekuni)]
}

new <- function(DT) {
  DT[ , localtime := anytime::anytime(timestamp, tz = tz)]
  DT[, Date := as.Date(localtime)]
  DT[, weekuni := paste0(lubridate::year(.BY[[1L]]), lubridate::week(.BY[[1L]])),
     keyby = "Date"]
  DT[, Date := NULL]
  # DT[, timestamp := NULL]
  DT[order(col), .(col, localtime, weekuni)]
}

bench::mark(old(DT1), new(DT2), check = FALSE, filter_gc = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>   expression     min    mean median    max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#>   <chr>      <bch:t> <bch:t> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 old(DT1)    22.39s  22.39s 22.39s 22.39s    0.0447    2.28GB     5     1
#> 2 new(DT2)     1.13s   1.13s  1.13s  1.13s    0.888   878.12MB     1     1
#> # ... with 1 more variable: total_time <bch:tm>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-06-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

Even if you don't you can still obtain 10-fold speedup by only using `paste` once per date:

```r
library(data.table)
NN = 1e7
# NN = 1e4
set.seed(32040)
DT <- data.table(
  col = seq_len(NN),
  timestamp = 1521872652 + sample(7000001, NN, replace = TRUE)
)
DT1 <- copy(DT)

DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)
tz <- "Africa/Addis_Ababa"

old <- function(DT) {
  DT$localtime<-  anytime::anytime(DT$timestamp, tz=tz) ###Lightning fast
  DT$weekuni <- paste(lubridate::year(DT$localtime), lubridate::week(DT$localtime), sep="")
  DT[, timestamp := NULL]
  DT[, .(col, weekuni)]
}

new <- function(DT) {
  DT[ , Date := anytime::anydate(timestamp, tz = tz)]
  DT[, weekuni := paste0(lubridate::year(.BY[[1L]]), lubridate::week(.BY[[1L]])),
     keyby = "Date"]
  DT[, Date := NULL]
  # DT[, timestamp := NULL]
  setorderv(DT[, .(col, weekuni)], "col")
}


bench::mark(old(DT1), new(DT2), check = TRUE, filter_gc = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>   expression     min    mean median    max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#>   <chr>      <bch:t> <bch:t> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 old(DT1)     22.2s   22.2s  22.2s  22.2s    0.0450    2.21GB     4     1
#> 2 new(DT2)      2.8s    2.8s   2.8s   2.8s    0.357     1.42GB     3     1
#> # ... with 1 more variable: total_time <bch:tm>
```

Comment: should maybe be careful to include the time of `as.Date` since `as.Date.POSIXct` contains the `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct` step that I think is bottlenecking a lot of things. OTOH OP might have other reasons to keep the `date` field around anyway in which case that conversion's a sunk cost.